# Explanation of Ethereum Alarm Clock

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapp-development

I unfortunately need the Ethereum Alarm Clock, but everything concerning this is either deprecated or unclear, could someone write very simple example? I've been fighting with that for a week and it's a dead end.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ethereum Alarm Clock](http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/). is a smart contract that registers actions and dates, and people can call the contract that calls the scheduled action.

But it doesn't wake itself up, it relied on users having an interest (an Ether reward) to do so. They call the clock function, which in return calls the contracts registered by anyone, and they get a reward for that (likely to cover more than the gas of course).

At the moment, the service is not really functioning. The last transaction is long ago, and if nobody calls the clock then your function is not executed.

Comment: Is it still not functional? Their blog seems pretty active. @Nicolas Bernard

Comment: @NicolasBernard Hi Nicolas while looking for questions about alarm clock I found your answer. I found your answer clear and I ask you if you can answer my question too [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/93319/ethereum-alarm-clock-and-scheduling). I am a beginner so I don't understand some concepts.