# scheduling of smart contract functions

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, nodes, scheduling

I am reading the alarm clock documentation http://docs.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/en/latest/ but there are things I don't understand. I have a dapp where the smart contract has different functions. For example: in the smart contract I have two functions:

- booking function
- refund function

I want the refund function to be called on a specific date (booking end date) and if there is a refund you have to return the money to the customer, but I don't want the customer to call this function manually at the end of the trip. I add for clarity that my refund function calls a method of another contract. This contract returns the result on a callback on the caller's contract
However, reading the documentation I am having difficulty.

- Is TransactionRequest a smart contract that indicates the function I want to call on a specific date (in my case the refund function)? So I have another smart contract?
- what is the requestFactory?
- is there a scheduling contract?
- is the TimeNodes a separate node besides my geth / parity node?

Unfortunately I have no code to show because I am a beginner and I am just trying to build an architecture with all the components, so I want to understand what to insert and if it is possible to execute the refund mechanism with the alarm clock.

Comment: I don't know the specifics of the latest ethereum alarm clock versions, but it seems to me that the contract addresses provided in the github in network folder haven't seen any activity for the last 3 years so I would not use it for anything but playing around as most likely nobody looks at it. Similarly to many DeFi services, rather than using a 3rd party, make a monitor page and allow anyone to use metamask and process the refunds (for a reward, same as the eth alarm clock). You'll be the only one to check until arbitrage gusy find it worth monitoring

Comment: The best way to do it is through openzeppelin defender (or) chainlink keepers instead of using ethereum clock which I don't think is worth exploring personally.